# I want to apply 3 images on a layout one at left,one at right and one at center...is it possible??? if yes then how?

Tags: android

**Android:How to set more than one image on single layout**

I want to apply 3 images on a single layout one at left,one at right and one at center...is it possible??? if yes then how??

Comment: Everything is possible,but what you have tried.?

Comment: Please post a sample screenshot to how it should look.

Comment: i was trying layer drawable and have set three images in that but not able to control their position and sizes..!!

Answer (score 2):

Spilling the beans here for you. Next time post anything you have tried, keeps people from downvoting your question. Assuming they are separate images:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@id/img1"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true
  />
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@id/img2"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true
  />
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@id/img3"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to have them all in one ImageView merge them in the same graphic using gimp/panit/photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"   
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layoutWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_1"/>
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"   
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layoutWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"   
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layoutWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image_3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

but this is just a poor example, it depends on what You want. Usualy you have to define multiple layouts for multiple screen support.....